# Dictionary array checks in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries with arrays. I want the dictionary from the primary list only if 'buckets' show up  in the secondary list of dictionary 'buckets' while 'labels' are a match.

```
primary = [{'buckets': [165, 27],
   'label': 'Andrew'}, {'buckets': [1364],
   'label': 'Matt'},{'buckets':[500, 60, 888], 'label':'John'}]

secondary = [{'buckets': [165, 1447],
  'label': 'Andrew'}, {'buckets': [1365, 15, 16],
  'label': 'Matt'}, {'buckets':[12,10,15], 'label':'Max'}]

data = {}

for x in primary:
    found = False
    for i in secondary:

        for num in x['buckets']:
            if x['label'] == i['label']:
                if num in i['buckets']:
                    found =True
                    break
    if found:
        data[x['label']] = x['buckets']
    else:
        data[i['label']] = i['buckets']

pprint.pprint(data)
```

If I change the matches around/ numbers in the array I do not get the right results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Desired output:
{'Andrew': [165, 27], 'Matt': [1365, 15, 16]}
```

This occurs sometimes but if i change Andrews numbers in secondary It may end up just this.

```
{'Matt': [1365, 15, 16]}
```

Comment: **The goal is to return the primary list dictionary if the primary dictionary shows up in then return secondary list dictionary if not return the secondary dictionary.**...... This statement is highly confusing and unclear... "shows up in" where?

Comment: @Bazingaa i edited the statement. When labels match i want to check if buckets from primary are in secondary. if that is yes return the dict in primary if that is is a no return the dict in secondary.

Comment: In such problems, it is often helpful for people who want to answer to have a desired sample output. How would the desired output look like in your case? Can you include that in the question?

Comment: @Bazingaa thank you good point i added a desired output plus the issue output.

Comment: The desired solution should be `{'Andrew': [165, 1447], 'Matt': [1365, 15, 16]}`. You want the lists from the secondary dictionaries, right?

Comment: I would not use lists here, why don't you do: `primary = {"Andrew" : {'bucket':...}, "Matt": {..` and same for `secondary`, then you can simply run through the keys of one and compare values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. The major point which I use here is `intersection` to check if there is a common value between two lists. If there is, then I take the list from `primary`. If not, then you take the list from `secondary` as you explained in the comment below. You don't need a `found` tag now

```
data = {}

for x in primary:
    for i in secondary:
        if x['label'] == i['label']:
            if list(set(x['buckets']).intersection(i['buckets'])):
                    data[x['label']] = x['buckets']
                    break
            else:
                data[x['label']] = i['buckets']

print(data)
# {'Andrew': [165, 27], 'Matt': [1365, 15, 16]}
```

Comment: It also needs to confirm if one of the primary key['buckets'] are in secondary key['buckets'] so to return primary Andrew 165 or 27 needs to be in secondary buckets otherwise take Secondary Andrew